# Control one light with two buttons

Tags: home-installation

I have a lamp in my flat that can be turned on and off with two different buttons, how does a circuit look like to realize that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdfqGn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The switch is normally referred to as Single-Pole Double-Throw. (SPDT)
(I had to look that up as it is called different in my native language)

This in contrast to a standard on/off switch which is called Single-Pole Single-Throw (SPST).

As you can imagine there are many other types like. Double-Pole Single-Throw and Double-Pole Double-Throw.

Comment: In electrician terms (rather than electronics), you will hear such switches called three-way switches in the US/Canada (as they have three terminals), and two-way switches (as they allow control from two locations) in most of the rest of the world.

Comment: In German (and in Dutch) it is (also) called ["Hotelschaltung".](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wechselschaltung)

Comment: Thanks so much for your diagram. I looked up SPST/SPDT to learn more but didn't understand any of those diagrams. This was is simple and clear.